# Generating random dataframes using unique elements from an existing dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, random, logic

I am trying to do some data manipulations using pandas. I have an excel file with two columns `x,y` . The number of elements in `x` corresponds to number of connections(`n_arrows`) it makes with an element in column `y`. The number of unique elements in column `x` corresponds to the number of unique points(`n_nodes`). What i want to do is to generate a random data frame(10^4 times) with the unique elements in `column x` and elements in `column y`? The code i was trying to work on is attached. Any suggestion will be appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('/home/amit/Desktop/playing_with_pandas.csv')
num_nodes = df.drop_duplicates(subset='x', keep="last")
n_arrows = [32]             #32 rows corresponds to 32 
n_nodes = [10]
n_arrows_random = np.random.randn(df.x)
```

[image: playing with data frames]

Comment: Could you show the `head` of your dataframe, and a sample of what a "simulated dataframe" might look like?

Comment: @the picture of data frame is added. By simulated dataframe i mean randomly changing the positions of elements in column x and y 10000 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 methods:

**Solution 1**: If you need the `x` and `y` values to be independently random:

Given a sample `df` (thanks @AmiTavory):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 1, 2], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Using `numpy.random.choice`, you can do this to select random values from your `x` column and random values from your `y` column:

```
def simulate_df(df, size_of_simulated_df):
    return pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.choice(df.x, size_of_simulated_df), 
                         'y':np.random.choice(df.y, size_of_simulated_df)})

>>> simulate_df(df, 10)
   x  y
0  1  3
1  1  3
2  1  4
3  1  4
4  2  1
5  2  3
6  1  2
7  1  4
8  1  2
9  1  3
```

The function `simulate_df` returns random values sampled from your original dataframe in the `x` and `y` columns. The size of your simulated dataframe can be controlled by the argument `size_of_simulated_df`, which should be an integer representing the number of rows you want.

**Solution 2**: As per your comments, based on your task, you might want to return a dataframe of random rows, *maintaining the x->y correspondence*. Here is a vectorized `pandas` way to do that:

```
def simulate_df(df=df, size_of_simulated_df=10):
    return df.sample(size_of_simulated_df, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)

>>> simulate_df()
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  2  4
3  2  4
4  1  1
5  1  3
6  1  3
7  1  1
8  1  1
9  1  3
```

**Assigning your simulated Dataframes for future reference**:

In the likely scenario you want to do some sort of calculation on your simulated dataframes, I'd recommend saving them to some sort of dictionary structure using a loop like this:

```
dict_of_dfs = {}

for i in range(100):
    dict_of_dfs['df'+str(i)] = simulate_df(df, len(df))
```

Or a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
dict_of_dfs = {'df'+str(i): simulate_df(df, (len(df))) for i in range(100)}
```

You can then access any one of your simulated dataframes in the same way you would access any dictionary value:

```
# Access the 48th simulated dataframe:
>>> dict_of_dfs['df47']
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  1
2  1  4
3  2  3
```

Comment: Oh, I thought the x->y correspondence should have been maintained. You understood it differently, I see.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong - I don't necessarily think your interpretation is incorrect, it's just that I didn't think of it.

Comment: See edits, You can pick which function best suits your needs

Comment: @sacul Say if want to generate a 100 for these random connections between elements of x and y. What i mean is 100 random rearrangements between unique elements in x to y.

Comment: @It will give me 100 rows. I donot want 100 rows. I want to keep the same number of rows like i had in the original data frame. But just need to randomly assign the values a 100 times

Comment: @sacul, this is wat i wanted. Thank you

Comment: @Sacul, What if i want to convert the dictionary to a dataframe again? Because i read like the value is stored as string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169107/discussion-between-amit-and-sacul).